# Avoid duplicate values on scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scrapying MOOCs data from [course talk](https://www.coursetalk.com/providers/edx/courses/6041x-introduction-to-probability-the-science-of-uncertainty-1) pages, and I'm having issues to clean some of the fields, E.G. The university name.

From the above link I want to get: **Massachusetts Institute of Technology**

This is the xpath I'm using for that field:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="course-info__school__name"]//text()').extract()
```

The problem here is that I'm getting duplicated values and empty strings from it:

```
[u'\n            ',
 u'University:\xa0',
 u'\n            Massachusetts Institute of Technology\n        ',
 u'\n            ',
 u'University:\xa0',
 u'\n            Massachusetts Institute of Technology\n        ']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip inner `span` by using `not` (to exclude inner child span node) function and `normalize-space` function to skip white-space only text strings and clean text:

```
//*[@class="course-info__school__name"]/text()[not(self::span)][normalize-space()]
```

In result you should get two equal strings with university name only:

```
[u'Massachusetts Institute of Technology',
 u'Massachusetts Institute of Technology']
```

And you can use python `set` to get unique names only:

```
>>> l = [u'Massachusetts Institute of Technology',
...      u'Massachusetts Institute of Technology']
>>> set(l)
set([u'Massachusetts Institute of Technology'])
```

If you need contents of first div only, you can get it by index 1 with just xpath:

```
(//*[@class="course-info__school__name"])[1]/text()[not(self::span)][normalize-space()]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason lies in the fact that there are two divs with class name `course-info__school__name`.

[image: a screen shot]

Therefore, to avoid duplicates, you could change the xpath so that it only select the first div element with class name of `course-info__school__name`

`response.xpath('(//div[@class="course-info__school__name"])[1]//text()').extract()`

which will will give you the result of

```
['\n            ', 
 'University:\xa0', 
 '\n            Massachusetts Institute of Technology\n        ']
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to get unique values always.

```
set(response.xpath('//*[@class="course-info__school__name"]//text()').extract())
```